# SemaphoreSlim problems with async tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, task, semaphore

I've been attempting to use SemaphoreSlim to limit the amount of concurrent tasks I have running at any one time but it seems to have no effect, likely down to my implementation which is why I'm here. My SemaphoreSlim code is like so:

First it's called by

```
await Task.Run(() => mc.StartAsync());
```

Calling this method

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{
    using (SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5))
    {
        foreach (var task in ThreadHandler.ThreadList)
        {
            await concurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => task.Operation.Start());
            }
            finally
            {
                concurrencySemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This in turn is starting a task from a list which looks like this, this is in a custom model with the task stored and created previously

```
public Task Operation { get; set; }
```

```
var t = new Task(async () =>
{
    await Task.Run(() => Method(input, sps));
});
```

Remembering my code doesn't work as I'd expect, is this the correct way to start something like this? I don't expect 3 tasks launching from a single point is a good idea. The main reason It's like this is because I'm executing an `Action<>` and couldn't figure out a way to await it alone. Do these tasks count towards the `SemaphoreSlim` limit?

After various tests I can confirm that my `SemaphoreSlim` code is just continuously executing the tasks, I added a large task delay into the list of tasks to see if I could stop it from executing which worked but new tasks were still launched... what am I missing?

My goal is to have a limit on the number of tasks concurrently running, if that wasn't clear. Thank you for any assistance!

EDIT: I think I've realised I'm only awaiting the starting of the task, not the completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I've realised I'm only awaiting the starting of the task, not the completion.

Indeed, that is the core of the problem.

[You shouldn't use the `Task` constructor, ever, at all, for anything](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html). Just pretend it doesn't exist. It will always lead you down an awkward path.

If you have an action you want to perform at a later time, you should use a delegate: [`Action` or `Func<T>` for synchronous work, and `Func<Task>` or `Func<Task<T>>` for asynchronous work](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html). E.g., if `Method` is synchronous, then you would have:

```
public Action Operation { get; set; }
...
Operation = () => Method(input, sps);
```

Then you can invoke it using `Task.Run` as such:

```
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    using (SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5))
    {
        var tasks = ThreadHandler.ThreadList.Select(async task =>
        {
            await concurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => task.Operation());
            }
            finally
            {
                concurrencySemaphore.Release();
            }
        }).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

The above code will work fine if `Operation` is `Action` (synchronous) or `Func<Task>` (asynchronous).

However, if it is `Action` (i.e., synchronous), then what you're really doing is *parallel* processing, not asynchronous concurrency, and there's built-in types that can help with that:

```
public void Process()
{
    // Only valid if Operation is Action, not Func<Task>!
    Parallel.ForEach(
        ThreadHandler.ThreadList,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 },
        task => task.Operation());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was extremely helpful. I managed to get SemaphoreSlim working correctly with Func<Task> after another days worth of research and testing, thank you again!